# How to verify IPN is pointing to my server from a Paypal User?

Tags: php, email, paypal

I'm currently developing an application which has to be able to process PayPal Payments from multiple e-mails and then has to redirected to my IPN class located at my server.

All the users of my application, have the possibility to set-up their own PayPal e-mail address into my system, and then the customers will pay directly to his PayPal Account (that means no intermediates).

But there's a problem, I **must ensure that my sellers are actually connected to my IPN**. Why? Because if they are not, when a customer makes a payment, the transaction will be actually completed, but they won't be able to download their purchased item, because my application could not receive the params.

So, the question is: how can I ensure this:

1. User has a valid Paypal Account (based on e-mail)
2. How do I know (and verify it each time) that this e-mail will sent a params directly to my server's IPN? (So important)
3. How do I verify each time that some customer makes a purchase?

Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

1. I would integrate [Express Checkout](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/express-checkout) and have them authorize you $1 (or whatever your minimum for currency is). This way you are guaranteed that the customer has a PayPal account with some balance. You can void the transaction via API and they get their money back.
2. There's no way to guarantee they send you IPN for their payments. The best bet would be to have them authorize you to run [third party calls](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/third-party/) on their behalf and take the money for them via your system.
3. See #2

Comment: Hello. So if they allow my e-mail on their third party calls, then it would be possible to redirect the money entirely to their account, am I right? btw, would you like to do this job? Are you in elance/odesk or something?

Comment: Third party calls means that I use my credentials to PayPal but the customer has authorized me to make the calls to their account. As such, when I run those calls the money goes straight to them. I simply become a middle man. It's more secure for them because if they ever want me to stop they just revoke my authorization.

I am not interested in any freelance jobs at this time.